# fwrite quotes in href

Tags: php, quotes, fwrite

I'm having trouble with href quotes inside the fwrite.
What I have no is something like this:

```
fwrite($fp, "Some text ".$SomeVar." some text :".$SomeVar.". Some text <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><br>Some text <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">");
```

Is there any way to make those href quotes mark as plain text?

I have read somewhere that using double quotes might help, but it doesn't. I have also tried:
`<a href="https://www.google.com/\" target="_blank\">`

Thank you.

Comment: If your string contains quotes, use single quotes for your string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to use single quotes when your string contains double quotes:

```
$string = '<a href="https://cia.gov">CIA</a>';
```

Or, you can escape the quotes like this:

```
$string = "<a href=\"https://cia.gov\">CIA</a>";
```

Comment: It doesn't work... I mean it does, but if viewed as php in exe links won't show at all.

Comment: update your question. code. expected output, actual output. what do you mean by exe links?

Comment: My mistake. I forgot that the game sees links differently. Sorry. Works good now.